# How to control sliding speed of SlidingDrawer in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I wanted to slow down the Sliding speed of Sliding Drawer.

I tried to take help from the below link but unable to understand this clumsy and heavy code.

[SlidingDrawer.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java.htm)

Please provide me some simple code as i am new to Android :(